# Salesforce: Remove PDF Quote Number Iteration on Generated Quote Document

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Is is possible to remove the Iteration of Document Name in Quote Document Generation via Salesforce CPQ? It is currently causing errors as the reps are adding this iteration which causes error in integration.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F2zA.png)

No iteration on Quote Document Generated